# Misaligned bibliography entry - Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, horizontal-alignment, formatting

**The problem:** 
my 26th bibliography entry, the final one, is off to the left. As a test, I added a 27th citation. Both the 26th and 27th were misaligned.

**My newbie hunch:** I'm using a template (Usenix) which links to a .bst file, but the .bst file has a comment saying it won't work with Bibtex 0.98i. I don't know which version of Bibtex I'm using or how I'd find out. But if I delete the contents of the .bst file, the PDF compiles the same way.

If you want any information I'm happy to provide it.

Here is my preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{usenix,epsfig,endnotes}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
```

And here is where the bibliography is entered:

```
{\footnotesize \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{addiction}}
\end{document}
```

Here's a section from the offending page:
[image]

Thanks,
Ivo

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the bib file code for entries 25 and 26. Please also indicate whether or not you load the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages.

Comment: The `s` in the url look strange - I bet this throws some error message.

Comment: The s's in the URL were supposed to be underscores, being very inexperienced I didn't know they would come out as superscript. I changed them to the underscore command and that solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op solved it by its own in code not showed to us ...